# Save the parents children in a var to append later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a markup in one of my website pages as follows:

```
<div id="mainPage">
   <div>
       <div><ul><li>etc.</li></ul>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div><ul><li>etc.</li></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

What the above means is that there's a main div in my website which has the content. I want to take all the children of the particular div and save it in a var, since I want to use that var later for something like `$('resurrectPage').append(someVar);` where `someVar` has the dom elements from the main page div.

How can all the children of a particular element be selected and added to a var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if #mainPage is your main div, you can get of it's children by

```
var someVar = $('#mainPage').children();
```

[Official api page](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Can `var someVar = $('#mainPage').children()` be used as `$('resurrectPage').append(someVar);` ? In another method that I have, I am using `$.get('http://someUrl', null, function(data){}, html)` so the `data` in above is the same as `someVar`? `$('resurrectPage').append(data);` As in `someVar` is an object, but what is `data`? Is it `html` or an `object`?

Comment: Yes, you can append that way.

Comment: For you second question, I can't say it's same or not in your ajax callback, it may be markup, json or any other thing. but `data` is a local variable in that method scope.

Comment: @user1240679: `data` is whatever the server returns.

Comment: `someUrl` is markup and not json or other things. But I wanted to understand  if `data` returned is markup, the are `data` in `$('#someDiv)'.append(data)` and and `$(#mainPage).children()` in `$('#someDiv)'.append($('#mainPage').children());` are both of the same type?

Comment: if `data` contains markup, yes, they work in similar way. if they both are string of element, they are same type. actually, i'm unclear about your question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

`$('#mainPage').html()` would give you the entire thing in a string `"<div>
       <div><ul><li>etc.</li></ul>   </div>   <div>       <div><ul><li>etc.</li></ul>   </div>"`

`$('#mainPage').children()`  would give you immidiate children `[div,div]`

`$('#mainPage').find('.div')` would giv =e you all the divs inside it `[div,div,div,div]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for jQuery `detach` method...

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

It will remove an element and store its contents, ready to be re-appended:

```
var a = p = $("a").detach()
```

Comment: I don't want to detach. just save the elements in a var. detachingis going t happen later automatically

Comment: Then use HungryCoder's method. But you really should do them in one go. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the HTML you can save the HTML: `var someVar = $("#mainPage").html();` and then append the HTML with the code you already have. Please tell me if I have misunderstood your question.